# Control systems Engineering

Tags: control, control-system

I am a third year student in Electrical Engineering, and I would like to get into Control systems. I was reading about the job ads and I noticed that I need to know PLC and HMI.
I don't know if they teach PLC and HMI in school, so I would like to get ahead of my career and start learning them as I have so much free time right now. does anyone know where I can start ? I want to self learn them, any insights on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are very practical hands-on type things. If you already know how to program in a few radically different computer languages (especially object-oriented for the HMI and an HDL (VHDL or Verilog) and perhaps assembly language of some kind) you'll pick it up very quickly.

PLCs often use ladder-logic programming, which is sort of an HDL, but it's implemented with sequential processing (which has implications for the way the programs behave).

I would think that for less than the cost of tuition for a University-level course you could pick up a commercial PLC, an HMI and the requisite software and run through a few simple projects. For example you could automate watering and nutrient dispensing of your garden, fish out that old bread maker from the closet and re-implement the logic in it, automate lights and animatronics for Halloween or Christmas etc.

Comment: the only programming language I have learned is C. that is it.

Comment: Time to expand your horizons, laddie. And be aware that, if you make a career out of engineering, you'll be learning new stuff the rest of your career.